# Unity - Polygon Collider Problems

Tags: c#

I'm making a Brick Breaker game and I have encountered a issue. I have a polygon collider in my paddle so the ball can hit sloped angles and go different directions, but here is the problem. Every time the ball hits the paddle's polygon collider, the ball goes slower and then when it hits something else it gets even slower. Also when the ball hits the paddle, the paddle moves in a random direction without me pressing nothing.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is there any friction forces?  Ideally when you bounce off an object the momentum (mass * velocity) should be the same.  Newton Law.  You only slow down when frictional forces are acting on the object.  Velocity is a vector with x,y,z components.  It should be with no friction that sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z**2) is a constant.  If you are slowing down it may be that that you are not getting the sqrt of the 3 vectors.

Comment: How do you get a sqrt of 3 vectors? I have no friction on the ball and on the paddle's collider.

Comment: It is the sum of the squares : sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z*2)  Is the game 2 dimensional or 3 demensional?  If 2-D then sqrt(x^2 + y^2).

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by taking out the rigidbody component of my paddle. Thanks a lot though!!